# Concatenating Values in SQL Server using a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I have been trying to concatenate values for a particular row. Say I have a query:

```
SELECT 
    tblContacts_2.contactid, 
    (COALESCE (tblSites_1.sitenm, '') 
     + COALESCE (' / ' + tblSites_1.sitenmalt, '') 
     + ' ' + COALESCE (tblSites_1.addr1, '') + ' ' 
     + COALESCE (tblSites_1.zipcodeid, '') ) AS SiteNameAddr, 
    tblSites_1.siteid 
FROM   
    dbo.tblcontacts AS tblContacts_2 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tjncsitecontacts AS tjncSiteContacts_1 ON tblContacts_2.contactid = tjncSiteContacts_1.contactid 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblsites AS tblSites_1 ON tblSites_1.siteid = tjncSiteContacts_1.siteid
```

The output for this is

```
ContactID   SiteNameAddr                              SiteID
--------------------------------------------------------------
 329        TWIN PARKS SOUTHWEST / TWIN PARKS SOUTH...   1
1788        TWIN PARKS SOUTHWEST / TWIN PARKS S....      1
```

What I want is, an output of this format where the sitenameaddrs for one contact id is concatenated like below with a count of site ids it is associated with:

```
ContactID    SiteNameAddr                                     CountSite
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
321          RIVERSIDE PARK /  3333 BROADWAY 10035, URBAN...      8
322          WESTVIEW 625 MAIN ST 10044                           1
```

The problem is, the following code fails while doing this -

```
SELECT 
    tblContacts_2.contactid, 
    dbo.Removelastchar(dbo.Strconcat(COALESCE (tblSites_1.sitenm, '') 
                                    + COALESCE (' / ' + 
                                    tblSites_1.sitenmalt, '') 
                                    + ' ' + COALESCE (tblSites_1.addr1, '') 
                                    + ' ' 
                                    + COALESCE (tblSites_1.zipcodeid, '') + 
                                    ', ')) 
                            AS SiteNameAddr, 
    Count(tblSites_1.siteid) AS CountSite 
FROM   
    dbo.tblcontacts AS tblContacts_2 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tjncsitecontacts AS tjncSiteContacts_1 ON tblContacts_2.contactid = tjncSiteContacts_1.contactid 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblsites AS tblSites_1 ON tblSites_1.siteid = tjncSiteContacts_1.siteid 
GROUP BY 
    tblContacts_2.contactid
```

Error:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "strconcat":
>   System.Data.SqlServer.TruncationException: Trying to convert return
>   value or output parameter of size 8086 bytes to a T-SQL type with a
>   smaller size limit of 8000 bytes.

This is because one of the contact ids has 92 sites associated with it and the concatenated string becomes too large. Also, `dbo.Removelastchar` and `dbo.Strconcat` are scalar functions so they can only return `nvarchar` and hence can't use `ntext` in them. Type-casting of data-type is not working either.

Please let me know what is the alternative to this. The concatenated string is picked up by VBA code in Access

Comment: Can't you use `nvarchar(max)` which holds up to **1 billion** characters? Wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: @marc_s I read that in the voice of Dr. Evil.

Comment: T-SQL function CONCAT should be able to handle nvarchar(max) values https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx if it doesn't return an nvarchar(max) automatically, cast one of the inputs as nvarchar(max) to force the return value